# How can I have an ImageView beside a multiline TextView and don't exceed the limit of parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, drawable

I am trying to align an `ImageView` besides to a `TextView`, but I am having troubles getting the expected result.

The `TextView` can have more than one line, therefore I am using `android:layout_width="0dp"`. However, because of this, `ImageView` is getting placed too far from `TextView`:

[image: Result with layout_width="0dp"]

If instead of using `android:layout_width="0dp"`, I set `layout_width="wrap_content"`, I get the expected result if there is enough screen space:

[image: Result with layout_width="wrap_content"]

In smaller screens the `TextView` is not split in multiple lines and hence exceeds the limits of the parent view:

[image: Result with layout_width="wrap_content" in small screen]

I also tried to use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/vc_estadio"` attribute of `TextView`, but then the drawable is too big:

[image: Result with android:drawableLeft="@drawable/vc_estadio"]

Finally, I also tried resizing the drawable, but then I have the same problem than with `android:layout_width="0dp"`. The image is too far from the text:

[image: Result with android:drawableLeft="@drawable/vc_estadio" and resizing the drawable]

What I expect is something like this in small screens:

[image: Expected result in small screens]

And this in bigger ones:

[image: Expected result in big screens]

The code I am using and trying to get working is this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/estadioImageView"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/vc_estadio"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/estadioTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/estadioTextView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/estadioTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/estadioTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Estadio Pedro Garrido (Jerez de la Frontera)"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/estadioImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `android:layout_width="0dp"` , as you are using `wrap_content` the constraint for width is not working so it's going outside when text is long instead of going to next line.

Use `ImageView` to show image as in `drawableLeft` you don't have control over the size.

**Final code :**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/start_guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.08" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/end_guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.92" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/estadioImageView"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/female_icon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/estadioTextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/estadioTextView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/start_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/estadioTextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/estadioTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Estadio Pedro Garrido (Jerez de la Frontera) "
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/end_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/estadioImageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**NOTE : UPDATE THE DRAWABLES USED AS I HAVE USED SAMPLE DRAWABLES**

**Final Output :**
[image]

Comment: Hi @Kamal Nayan , thank you for trying to help, but like I said, I already tried using `ImageView` and `android:layout_width="0dp"`, but then the image is too far from the text (see first image).

Comment: I have updated the answer, kindly try the code and inform if you need help with something else.

Comment: That alignes the text to left, so the image and text and aligned lilke I want, but then I cannot use `android:gravity="center"` in `estadioTextView`. See images 6 and 7 above to understand what is the result I expect.

Comment: So this you want ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bjuj.png

Comment: Paste the link of image which you want as output. I will update the code accordingly and inform you please wait for 20-25 mins

Comment: I really appreciate your help @Kamal Nayan . This is the expected result on small screens, as you can see if the text is too long, then is split in two lines: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Y61.png
When the screen is big enough and the text can be in in one line only, I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bjuj.png

Comment: Okay updating the code in few minutes.